# C# - Perform action if, not when, a key is pressed

Tags: c#, multithreading, input

I'm writing a multithreaded program that aborts when the user presses Escape. The thread that executes this is as follows:

```
private static void ESC_PRESS_THREAD()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(EQ_CALC);
        t.Start();
    }

private static void EQ_CALC()
{
    if (ConsoleKey == ConsoleKey.Escape)
        stockEq.ToList().ForEach(sq => sq.Abort());
}
```

However, this causes the program to wait for user input before it continues. How do I not do anything if Esacpe is not pressed?

Comment: For something like this you usually need the thread function to have `while(shouldContinue) { ... }`, and then have another method that sets `shouldContinue = false;`

Comment: You need to send in cancelation token.